# Fatal NServiceBus exception when starting endpoint, cannot open database

Tags: c#, sql-server, nservicebus

We just made some changes to our project and deployed it. We have 7 endpoint databases in our SQL Server database for NServiceBus. We recently added 2 more. One of the two services using one of the two new endpoints fails to start. When looking at our log file we see the following error:

> *FATAL NServiceBus.GenericHost [(null)] - Exception when starting endpoint.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "A_NSBEP_WebEventProcessor" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'xxxx'*

The connection string is

> *'connection.connection_string'='Data Source=localhost\DevSQLServer;Initial Catalog=A_NSBEP_WebEventProcessor;Integrated Security=true;Enlist=true'*

All of the connection strings are configured in OctopusDeploy. They are all identical except obviously for the database name. All of the other services start and login to their respective endpoint with no problem. I even went through the process of creating a .udl file, connecting to the database and using that slightly different connection string. Still without success.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "Login failed for user 'XXXXXXXXXXX". It sounds like the user is not permissioned correctly for the two new databases.

Comment: You are using Windows credentials since you have "Integrated Security=true;".  So the only thing that changes in the "Initial Catalog"?  That means the credentials of the database doesn't allow user to connect.  Check working database and compare credentials with non working.  Usually we use a group account so users in same windows group can use the database.  SQL Server can use work either by adding each user to credential of data base or use a window group account and add users to the windows group.